# Build failed while building Dlib c++ using VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, dlib

I tried to build dlib using VS 2015 with release x64 but the build failed facing some errors and the same thing happens with debug x64
here is the errors that shows up after building dlib project with release x64

```
 auto.cpp
    2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib- 
    19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(77): error C2535: 
    'unknown-type 
   dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const 


  dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> 
    &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(84): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>' being compiled (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(78): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(79): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(80): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(81): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(82): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(83): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\filtering\kalman_filter.cpp)
2>  sockets_kernel_1.cpp
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(77): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(84): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>' being compiled (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(78): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(79): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(80): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(81): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(82): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(83): error C2535: 'unknown-type dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go(T &&,const dlib::matrix<double,0,1,dlib::default_memory_manager,dlib::row_major_layout> &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
2>  c:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\global_optimization/find_max_global.h(76): note: see declaration of 'dlib::gopt_impl::call_function_and_expand_args<max_unpack>::go' (compiling source file C:\dlib-19.15\dlib-19.15\source\dlib\svm\auto.cpp)
```

Comment: I'm afraid we need to see some code not just the error

Comment: @nada there is no code , I'm trying to build the Dlib project that I've generate using Cmake

Comment: Solved by downloading visual studio 2015 update 3 and rebuilding Dlib as known